# Use arrayvalues to access (sub)arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I want to see if a certain value exists in one of the arrays I have defined, there is one main array and several "sub" arrays, they are defined like this:

```
var main = ['header', 'firstname', 'surname', 'tel'];
var firstname_label = ['Hank', 'Dave', 'Erin', 'Jessica'];
var surname_label = ['Michaels', 'McHankering', 'Jameson', 'Lloydd', 'Eagon', 'Philips'];
var tel_label = ['mobile', 'landline'];
```

I want to check the sub arrays with a variable I have, I was thinking something along these lines:

```
for (i=1;i<=mainCount;i++)
{
    jQuery.inArray(var_x, main[i]_label)
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Have you thrown it into a page (or jsfiddle) and seen if it works?

Comment: Pretty sure he knows it's not going to work, it's just pseudo code to describe what he wants to do.

Comment: the above for loop is just pseudo code to demonstrate what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an `Object`:

```
var main = ['header', 'firstname', 'surname', 'tel'];

var sub =
{
    firstname_label: ['Hank', 'Dave', 'Erin', 'Jessica'],
    surname_label: ['Michaels', 'McHankering', 'Jameson', 'Lloydd', 'Eagon', 'Philips'],
    tel_label: ['mobile', 'landline']
};

for (i=1;i<=mainCount;i++)
{
    jQuery.inArray(var_x, sub[main[i] + '_label'])
}
```

The alternative would be to use `eval` to select the variable name, but don't go there.

Comment: That did the trick, for anybody interested this is the code I'm using:
 for (i=1;i<=mainCount;i++)
 {
  if (jQuery.inArray(var_x, sub[main[i] + '_label']) >= 0)
  {
   [DO SOMETHING]
  }
 }